# 404 when fetching image with webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-file-loader

I'm following this link to add images to my bundle:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/

I have the following files structure in my root folder:

index.html

index.js

images folder (with svg's)

This is my webpack.config.js

```
// Generated using webpack-cli https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli

const path = require('path');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const stylesHandler = 'style-loader';



const config = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        host: 'localhost'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Custom template',
            // Load a custom template (lodash by default)
            template: 'index.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'images',
            },
        ]
    }
};


module.exports = () => {
    if (isProduction) {
        config.mode = "production";
    } else {
        config.mode = "development";
    }
    return config;
};
```

I'm using the following webpack modules:

```
    "webpack": "^5.64.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.6.0",
    "wepack-cli": "0.0.1-security"
```

In my js file, I'm trying to add an image to an SVG element by doing:

```
.attr('xlink:href', 'images/virtual-machine.svg')
```

But I'm getting 404.

Comment: The string literal path 'images/virtual-machine.svg' won't just work. You need to import asset via `import` or `require`

Comment: @JózefPodlecki - I'm probably missing some info but when looking at http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server, I don't see any images folder so if I use require via code, I assume it would also fail.

Comment: Now Im not sure if `type: 'images'` would even work. What webpack version are you using? In webpack 5 there is `type: 'asset/resource'` which will work only once you import it directly in the code

Comment: @JózefPodlecki - updated my post with webpack packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [resource](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) asset module

```
  rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
        ]
```

Now the webpack must be aware you are using this image. Following import should work.

**Make sure the path is correct as it will lookup path from the current folder**

```
import virtualMachineSvg from 'images/virtual-machine.svg'

.attr('xlink:href', virtualMachineSvg)
```

Or `require`

```
const virtualMachineSvg = require('images/virtual-machine.svg');

.attr('xlink:href', virtualMachineSvg)
```